# How to set a PostgreSQL function as default value in GORM?

Tags: postgresql, go, go-gorm

I want something like:

```
type User struct {
    ID          int     `sql:"default:<myfunction>"`
}
```

Is this possible with GORM?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Have you tried it?  You can do

```
time.Time `sql:"DEFAULT:current_timestamp"`
```

and it will use the "current_timestamp" function.  If you want the default to be the string `current_timestamp`, you would do

```
time.Time `sql:"DEFAULT:'current_timestamp'"`
```

So, in short, yes, it is possible.  You would just do:

```
type User struct {
    ID          int     `sql:"DEFAULT:myfunction"`
}
```

Comment: Turns out the problem was I needed to specify the type and primary key to get it working:
    ID   uint64 `gorm:"primary_key" sql:"type:bigint; DEFAULT:id_generator()"`

Comment: cant seem to add a default value at all? EpisodeNum int  `json: "episodenum" gorm: "type:INTEGER; DEFAULT:0"`

Comment: @user1232726 try `json:"episodenum" gorm:"type:INTEGER" sql:"DEFAULT:0"`