# sql struct tag syntax for declaring default value of string

Tags: go, go-gorm

Do I need to enclose with qoutes (**''**) for string type or not

```
type Car struct {
    Transmission             string `gorm:"column:transmission" sql:"DEFAULT:'manual'" json:"transmission"`
}
```

```
type Car struct {
    Transmission             string `gorm:"column:transmission" sql:"DEFAULT:manual" json:"transmission"`
}
```

In db, the data_type is ENUM

Comment: take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33573306/using-gorm-is-there-a-way-for-me-to-set-a-default-value-as-a-postgresql-functio

Answer (score 1):

You can set the default value with the gorm struct tag - I have found the SQL struct tag to be ignored by gorm (with mariadb):

```golang
type Car struct {
    gorm.Model
    Transmission string `gorm:"default:manual"`
}
```

Or you could add a bit of type checking on the go side:

```golang
type Transmission string

const (
    Automatic Transmission = "automatic"
    Manual    Transmission = "manual"
)

func (t *Transmission) Scan(value interface{}) error {
    *t = Transmission(value.([]byte))
    return nil
}

func (t Transmission) Value() (driver.Value, error) {
    return string(t), nil
}

type Car struct {
    gorm.Model
    Transmission Transmission `gorm:"default:manual"`
}
```

Either way - I had to define the enum directly in mariadb, it wouldn't produce an enum via the automigrate function of gorm.

```sql
create table demo.cars (
    transmission enum('automatic', 'manual') default 'manual' not null
);
```

Answer (score 0):

In short, yes you need to enclose the value with quotes.

```
string `sql:"DEFAULT:'default_value'"`
```

Otherwise, it will look for default or declared function.